# In anomaly detection of time series, should global outliers and contextual outliers be separated?

Tags: python, outliers, seasonality, anomaly-detection

I am trying to create a pipeline in Python which automatically identifies global and contextual anomalies of a time series.

Which one of these approaches do you believe is more correct?

Method 1)

1. Detect global outliers using z-score threshold.
2. Remove the outliers from the time series and impute values
3. Detect if seasonality/periodicity is present
4. If yes on 3) perform seasonal decomposition
5. Detect contextual outliers using z-score threshold on residuals.
6. Combine both groups of outliers.

Method 2)

1. Detect global outliers using z-score threshold.
2. Remove the outliers from the time series and impute values
3. Detect if seasonality/periodicity is present
4. If yes on 3) perform seasonal decomposition
5. Remove seasonality and trend **from original signal potentially containing global outliers as well**
6. Detect contextual outliers **and** global outliers using z-score threshold on residuals.

Method 3)

Something else which you know of?

**Appreciate any insights or tips!**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the nature of your anomalies. If global and contextual outliers co-exist often, and outliers are common outliers in general, and are extreme enough, have clusters or otherwise could impact the seasonal decomposition, then something like method 1 *may* work better. In all other cases it is just additional complexity, including more hyperparameters to tune to each good performance.

Method 2 is simpler, so implement it first. Evaluate how well it performs. If it is insufficient, then consider a more complex method based on the short-comings that have been identified. Which may not be